# Apache Server status, is this a bad sign?

Tags: apache-2.2, performance, connection, optimization

I've been monitoring my Apache Status lately, and a lot of my users are saying how slow the site is to respond. Here is the Apache Status:

```
Current Time: Tuesday, 21-Jun-2011 20:58:45 EDT
Restart Time: Sunday, 19-Jun-2011 13:06:38 EDT
Parent Server Generation: 299
Server uptime: 2 days 7 hours 52 minutes 7 seconds
Total accesses: 5586382 - Total Traffic: 3.5 GB
CPU Usage: u10.71 s12.32 cu295.34 cs0 - .158% CPU load
27.8 requests/sec - 18.2 kB/second - 671 B/request
39 requests currently being processed, 10 idle workers
```

I'm comparing that with Apache's status found here:
http://www.apache.org/server-status
And mine looks really slow compared to their average 4.5MB/Sec!

Here is my beloved httpd.conf:

```
Timeout 60
TraceEnable Off
ServerSignature Off
ServerTokens ProductOnly
FileETag None
<IfModule prefork.c>
MinSpareServers 6
MaxSpareServers 16
</IfModule>
ServerLimit 350
MaxClients 250
MaxRequestsPerChild 5000
KeepAlive On
KeepAliveTimeout 3
MaxKeepAliveRequests 200
```

Server Specs are:

```
Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5620 @ 2.40GHz x 10
2GB Ram
```

Is this a problem, or just typical results?
What can I do to boost the speed of my connections?

Comment: You forgot to tell us how fast your Internet connection is. Especially the uplink speed is important.

Answer (score 1):

There are a whole host of issues that can be causing Apache to slow down - insufficient RAM, insufficient CPU, insufficient network bandwidth, slow harddisks, etc.

That said, you need to use a proper benchmarking tool to stress out your machine and see where any bottlenecks lie.

A popular benchmark tool for Apache is - [Apache Bench](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/programs/ab.html). You can use it and monitor your server under different types of load.